# Change text in text box based on the text brought in from Query in Report - Microsoft Access / Visual Basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio, ms-access, report

I am attempting to clean up a Report created in Microsoft Access where an commonly recurring field from my Query is imported. Lets say this text reads "My Cool Query Field".

As this same text line is pretty common, I would like to shorten it up as the Report is generated. Lets say I want it to read "My Cool Field".

Right now I have some simple IfThen code under my Report:

```
If myTextBox.Text = "My Cool Query Field" Then
    myTextBox.Text = "My Cool Field"
End If
```

but am receiving the error: "Compile Error Invalid: Outside Procedure Access".

Comment: Where do you have this if statement? I believe you have the If outside of a procedure/sub/function

Comment: Ah yes, I believe that was the problem, I think I must have deleted my sub area by accident trying to clean some stuff up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead try something like this

Inside of the textbox `=myCoolFix([column])`

Behind the Scenes in a module:

```
public sub myCoolFix(mytext) as string

If myText = "My Cool Query Field" Then
    myCoolFix = "My Cool Field"
End If

end sub
```